# "Class type redefinition" error between header and source files

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

So I'm having a problem which I'm sure there is an extremely obvious solution for, but I just can't seem to figure it out.  Basically, when I try to do class definitions in my headers and implementation in my source files, I am getting an error saying that I am redefining my classes.  Using Visual C++ 2010 Express.

Exact error: "error C2011: 'Node' : 'class' type redefinition"

Example code included below:

Node.h:

```
#ifndef NODE_H
#define NODE_H
#include <string>

class Node{
public:
    Node();
    Node* getLC();
    Node* getRC();
private:
    Node* leftChild;
    Node* rightChild;
};

#endif
```

Node.cpp:

```
#include "Node.h"
#include <string>

using namespace std;


class Node{
    Node::Node(){
        leftChild = NULL;
        rightChild = NULL;
    }

    Node* Node::getLC(){
        return leftChild;
    }

    Node* Node::getRC(){
        return rightChild;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
class Node{
    Node::Node(){
        leftChild = NULL;
        rightChild = NULL;
    }

    Node* Node::getLC(){
        return leftChild;
    }

    Node* Node::getRC(){
        return rightChild;
    }

}
```

you declare the class twice in your code, the second time being in your .cpp file. In order to write the functions for your class you would do the following

```
Node::Node()
{
    //...
}

void Node::FunctionName(Type Params)
{
    //...
}
```

no class is required

Comment: I had the same problem as the person who asked the question. However, where do I put my variables (which are private in the class)?

Answer (score 2):

You're redefining the Node class, as it is saying. The .cpp file is just for the implementation of the functions.

```
//node.cpp
#include <string>

using namespace std;

Node::Node() {
  //defined here
}

Node* Node::getLC() {
  //defined here
}

....
```