# “Class type redefinition” error between header and source files (Different Case)

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I have seen this question: ["Class type redefinition" error between header and source files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13484178/class-type-redefinition-error-between-header-and-source-files)

If you'll just say a **duplicate** of the above question, please check first the code below.

The problem is that the "Class type redefinition" should not happened because I think I have done it properly.

Here is the code.

**TTSpeech.h**

```
#include <wtypes.h>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

class TTSpeech
{
  public:
    enum State
    {
        State_Loaded,
        State_Unloaded,
    };

    TTSpeech();
    virtual ~TTSpeech();

    virtual bool isAvailable() = 0;

    virtual bool load() = 0;
    virtual bool unload() = 0;

    virtual bool isLoaded() const = 0;

    virtual bool say(const std::string &sentence) = 0;

    virtual bool setVolume(int volume) = 0;
    virtual bool setPitch(int pitch) = 0;
    virtual bool setRate(int rate) = 0;

    virtual bool setVoice(const std::string &voice) = 0;

    virtual std::vector<std::string> getVoices() const = 0;
};
```

**TTSpeech.cpp**

```
#include "TTSpeech.h"

TTSpeech::TTSpeech()
{
//code
}

TTSpeech::~TTSpeech()
{
//code
}
```

The only unusual thing that I have done is to remove the files from the solution, relocate the above file to a folder because of this issue: [cannot open include no such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7789969/fatal-error-c1083-cannot-open-include-file-xyz-h-no-such-file-or-directory). Then re-add the files to the solution. I'm using Visual Studio 2012 running of Windows 8

Comment: More like you need to define include guard

Comment: Ahh.. I see. I didn't know that first few line are important. XD